# Winform Application communicate with my web UI in Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, winforms, google-chrome

I have 2 applications. One is C# Winform application. The other is a web page.(but, this web page has to be opened by chrome browser only.)

Now, I launched my winform application on my windows desktop. From the winform application, there is a button, I click that button, it will open my web page by using the local chrome browser.

```
string path = GetChromePath();
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.FileName = path;
p.StartInfo.Arguments = url;
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
returnProcess = p;
rc = p.Start();
```

Now, I have 2 application running on my windows desktop - the C# winform app and the chrome web page client.

Now, I want to implement bi-direction communication methods between the C# winform app client and the chrome web page client.

Details:

1. I want my web page (maybe use javascript or other skill) can have a method to send customized message to my C# winform app client, then my winform application gets the message and take the corresponding steps inside the winform application.
2. Vice versa, I want my winform application client can have a method to send message to my web page opened in Chrome process on same desktop, then my web page gets the message and take the corresponding steps inside the web page itself.

How can I develop such a model by using .Net C# and web page html DOM and javascript technologies in both applicaitions?

I'd appreciate it if anyone have help me with that. A code sample is always great.

Comment: Probably you can try from your WinForm using TcpClient and from Chrome, you must develop first a plugin, which can be contacted using TcpClient. Or try with WebRTC.

Comment: You can use SignalR. The Winform will be a C# client, the web page wil lbe a javascript client. Just google "SignalR Js client" and "SignalR WinForm Client"

Comment: Hi, Thanks! Can you please share with me a simple code sample for both SignalR Js client and Signal WinForm Client?

Comment: The simply, You can comunicate by your DB (SQL or etc..) Only create a table (or more) for the messages, read the wanted masseges and manage statuses.

Answer (score 0):

You can display your web page using the browser component for .Net without using an external browser. In this case the user should not have a pre-installed browser.

I work with the team, which created appropriate browser component – [DotNetBrowser](http://www.teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser).

This component supports interaction with Javascript and DOM.

You can get more information and examples regarding your case here:
[Calling .NET from JS](https://sites.google.com/a/teamdev.com/dotnetbrowser-support/documentation/calling-net-from-javascript)